# Java 11: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.ruedigermoeller.serialization.FSTObjectInput

Tags: java

I am upgrading project from Java 8 to 11. In Java 8, functionality works fine but In Java 11, it gives runtime error. Any workaround? Any dependency needs to be added?

Getting following exception with Java 11:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/ruedigermoeller/serialization/FSTObjectInput
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.ruedigermoeller.serialization.FSTObjectInput
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: How are you running them? If you are running them straight out of your IDE, it possible the java 8 version is being run with additional classpath arguments.

Comment: I am running it inside Eclise IDE with Open JDK (11). Meanwhile, I will check external dependency.

Comment: Thanks Locke for the quick response. Found the root cause. The required dependency was excluded from one of jar in pom.xml and it was causing the issue.

<exclusion>
 <groupId>de.ruedigermoeller</groupId>
 <artifactId>fst</artifactId>
</exclusion>

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. The required dependency was excluded from one of jar in pom.xml and it was causing the issue.

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>de.ruedigermoeller</groupId>
    <artifactId>fst</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```